# PS script not deleting file as scheduled task

Tags: performance, powershell

Can someone help me understand why this scheduled script doesn't run as intended: The file is not reliably deleted at the start of the next day (runs correctly 3-4X out of 5 whether machine is powered on or out of sleep mode (S3). How to get it to always delete the previous day file?

```
$Path = "H:\foobar.txt"

if (Test-Path $Path) {Get-ChildItem $Path | 
Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime).ToString() -lt ((get-date).AddDays(-1)).ToString() } | 
Remove-Item -Force }

('{0:MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt}' -f (Get-Date)) | Add-Content -Path $Path 
EXIT
```

snippet from output showing carryover into next day:

April 27, 2020 9:31:18 PM 
**April 28, 2020 7:16:37 AM**
April 28, 2020 5:31:45 PM
**April 29, 2020 7:16:37 AM**
April 29, 2020 11:17:02 PM
**April 30, 2020 6:02:06 AM**
April 30, 2020 6:17:02 PM
**May 01, 2020 6:27:28 AM**
May 01, 2020 7:17:02 AM

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that the variable `$Path` contains the path to a single file, you could shorten the code like:

```
$Path = "H:\foobar.txt"

# try and get a FileInfo object from the file in the path
$file = Get-Item -Path $Path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($file) {
    # the file was found, check if it is older than yesterday (midnight)
    if ($file.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date) {
        $file | Remove-Item -Force
    }
}

# Add-Content will create the file if it does not yet exist
('{0:MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt}' -f (Get-Date)) | Add-Content -Path $Path
```

Required of course is that the user running the scheduled task has write access to the `H:\` path..

Comment: Thanks for the condensed code, however your suggestion isn't working: File is not being deleted prior to adding content.  User has write access to H:\ path.  This is surely frustrating.  Sorry its taken so long, I've been testing over 24 hour blocks (only way I can test reliably). I have had some success with the original script using -NoProfile -Executionpolicy bypass -file "C:\test.ps1" to schedule the task, but have not been able to replicate with the your script.  The execution policy local machine is already set to unrestricted, so not clear why this would make a difference.